# accsess url with different url name

Tags: javascript, html

i tried to access website with different url names, example 'https://campus.champs.asia/mobile/login.php' but just write campus.champs.asia in browser and the result it should be same with content of campus.champs.asia/mobile/login.php.

the point is code in window.open is

```
window.open('https://campus.champs.asia','_self','location=yes');
```

but when i open it it should be content of

```
window.open('https://campus.champs.asia/mobile/login.php','_self','location=yes');
```

```
<html>
<head>
<title>NestorApp</title>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    function gotoWeb()
    {
         window.open('https://campus.champs.asia/mobile/login.php','_self','location=yes');
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Sounds like you'd need a redirection on the server-side. Where exactly the address is written "_in browser_", and how is `gotWeb` function called?

Comment: Does your problem happen on the client or server? If the server redirects you to another url there’s not much you can do about it.

Comment: If you're opening it in _self, why not use `window.location.href`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not too clear what you're trying to do here.

I assume you want a user which navigates to `https://campus.champs.asia` automatically redirected to `https://campus.champs.asia/mobile/login.php` by the browser, do you?

In this case just place the following **index.html** file to `https://campus.champs.asia`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    location.replace("https://campus.champs.asia/mobile/login.php");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i want navigate to https://campus.champs.asia/mobile/login.php but access use url   https://campus.champs.asia. that's it